# Accessing pages with session variables

Tags: php

I have created an application that holds and use session variables. At the end of the application a page is created with different data from the database using conditions that depends on session variables. I know that if I close the browser and try to access that last one page nothing will be displayed because the session has expired.

How can I store those session variables and still make the conditions but can access the page even if I close the browser and the session expires?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options here, you can use Cookies to store a user's session data - they are basically key-value stores in the user's browser that persist after the user has ended their session - take a look here for a tutorial on them: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpcookies.php

You could also look into storing the user's data in a database and then loading it every time a user visits your site - with this method you can store more complex data and store it more securely.

And you could also (as others have suggested) simply use the $_GET[] variables in PHP - here's a tutorial for that: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php

Comment: GET vars are traditionally used in form submissions, but you would simply construct a URL such as http://example.com/page.php?myVar=123&anotherVar=321

Comment: can we go in private and explain it to me? but what about the session variables?

Comment: Right this is how you would do it: use SESSION variables throughout your app, until the final page, when you're generating the final page, put all the SESSION variables in the URL as GET variables. And use the GET vars to generate the output. Make sense?

Comment: Like this:  $_GET['nr_chestionar']=$_SESSION['nr_chestionar']  ??

Comment: No, when you send the user to the final page, you would send them to a URL featuring those vars, so it would be: http://example.com/page.php?nr_chestionar=123

Answer (score 0):

Use GET query string instead of a session.

a page with address http://example.com/index.php?condition=1&filter=2 would always display the same content. That's what query strings are for

Answer (score 0):

You can store that values of the session variables up to a certain point inside a server-side persistence unit, like a DB, and access it in case the session does not contain any valid data.

You can also use session restoring using a token stored in the COOKIE to restore the session the next time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not storing sensitive information, you can use [cookies](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php).

Otherwise, save in the db your settings.